# Sublime text 3 annoying menu white line bug

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3

I'm seeing this white line under sublime menu no matter what theme I'm using, any ideas on how to solve this?

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

[See bug HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1mg5.png)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone have the same problem.

Updating sublime to version 3.2 solved my issue